# Post force eject disk is not showing in finder

Tags: macos

After force ejecting in EI capitan , My disk  showing in disk utility unix command but not showing in disk utility window and i have done as mentioned by setting PRAM but still it is not showing it neither in finder not in DU. pls help

Comment: So if you restart the Mac - what does `diskutil list` output when you run that command? Does that matching what Finder shows when you use the go menu to look at the computer view? (the restart is critical to get consistent results in your case)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for revert. In diskutil list command i am able to see the external hard disk but in disk utility app it is unable to launch itself when external hard disk is attached. In finder also external hard disk is not visible.

Comment: Hi , can anyone help me!